# ComboBox selected value not working

Tags: c#, sql

I am having problems with my code, basically i am trying to have a combo box that will display teams and when a team is selected it will display the players connected to that team on a listbox. Problem is is that i have had many errors with it

Here is the code to fill the combo boxes with teams

```
   String sqlTeam = @"select * from Team";
        daTeam = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlTeam, connStr);
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBTeam = new SqlCommandBuilder(daTeam);
        daTeam.FillSchema(dsCIF, SchemaType.Source, "Team");
        DataTable dtTeam = new DataTable();
        daTeam.Fill(dsCIF, "Team");
        daTeam.Fill(dtTeam);

        cmbTeam1.DataSource = dtTeam;
        cmbTeam1.ValueMember = "TeamID";
        cmbTeam1.DisplayMember = "TeamName";

        cmbTeam2.DataSource = dtTeam;
        cmbTeam2.ValueMember = "TeamID";
        cmbTeam2.DisplayMember = "TeamName";
```

When the team is changed in the combo box it will refill the listbox with the players connected to that team, here is the code for the listboxes

```
  sqlPlayers3 = @" Select PlayerID, PlayerForename, PlayerSurname, PlayerAge, PlayerStatus, (Playerforename +' '+Playersurname) as FullName from Player where TeamID  = @cmb";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmb", int.Parse(cmbTeam1.SelectedValue.ToString()));

        String connStr5 = Properties.Resources.cString;
        SqlDataAdapter daPlayer4 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlPlayers3, Properties.Resources.cString);
        DataTable dtPlayers3 = new DataTable();
        daPlayer4.Fill(dtPlayers3);

        lbTeam1Goal1.DataSource = dtPlayers3;
        lbTeam1Goal1.ValueMember = "PlayerID";
        lbTeam1Goal1.DisplayMember = "FullName";


        lbTeam1Bookings1.DataSource = dtPlayers3;
        lbTeam1Bookings1.ValueMember = "PlayerID";
        lbTeam1Bookings1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

Problem is that i keep getting this error when i load the form it highlights this line of code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmb", int.Parse(cmbTeam1.SelectedValue.ToString()));


System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in correct format.'
```

I have approached this many different ways but the code just does not seem to work.  I am using a SQL database and it is connected to visual studio c#. Is there anything i am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `cmbTeam1.SelectedValue.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your program

The error that you are seeing `'Input string was not in correct format.'` is caused because the `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged()` event handler is firing as soon as you bind your data.  You are binding your data before you have defined your `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`.  Which means that your `SelectedValue` attribute will not know which column holds the SelectedValue.

Always define your `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` before you bind your data.  Like this:

```
 //...
 lbTeam1Goal1.ValueMember = "PlayerID";
 lbTeam1Goal1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
 lbTeam1Goal1.DataSource = dtPlayers3; //databinding goes last

 lbTeam1Bookings1.ValueMember = "PlayerID";
 lbTeam1Bookings1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
 lbTeam1Bookings1.DataSource = dtPlayers3;
```

Next, you are not using your parameters, because your DataAdapter is using the query string instead of the command object.  Try this:

```
 sqlPlayers3 = @" Select PlayerID, PlayerForename, PlayerSurname, PlayerAge, PlayerStatus, 
     (Playerforename +' '+Playersurname) as FullName from Player 
     where TeamID  = @cmb";
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlPlayers3); //SQL goes in the command constructor
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmb", int.Parse(cmbTeam1.SelectedValue.ToString()));

 String connStr5 = Properties.Resources.cString;
 //SqlDataAdapter daPlayer4 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlPlayers3, Properties.Resources.cString); //not this way
 SqlDataAdapter daPlayer4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, Properties.Resources.cString); //this will work better
 DataTable dtPlayers3 = new DataTable();
 daPlayer4.Fill(dtPlayers3);
 //...
```

Before you change your code, you might find it interesting to put a breakpoint on the line that does `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue`.  You will see that the `SelectedIndexChanged` even was firing 3 times: 1) when you set `DataSource`, 2) when you set `ValueMember`, and 3) when you set `DisplayMember`.  After the change, it will fire once when you set the `DataSource`.